# Is a python appengine app with no firestore security rules insecure?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

**I have a Google App Engine Standard Environment application written in Python 3, using Flask as the framework, and firestore in native mode as the database. All of the database calls are done in the App Engine code, hidden behind Flask end points/views/handlers.**  Client browsers do not execute any javascript that directly call the firestore database. Client side javascript is basically 'dumb' code used for cosmetics.  The only time client side javascript does "anything" is when a user creates a new account or logs in using the [firebase auth ui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/firebaseui).

Having said so, I noticed that some online resources mention that it is absolutely necessary to secure the firestore database since anything that is not disallowed by security rules are basically allowed (i.e. the firestore database is insecure by default), however, I suspect that this is only the case for apps that have thick clients (i.e. the client side code or javascript is in charge of doing the heavy lifting of querying and writing to firestore).

So my question is, **is writing these security rules necessary only for mobile/web clients and not for firestore databases accessed only by server side code?** Or is it necessary for all firestore projects to define these security rules? If so, then I would appreciate any pointers as to where to find reasonable default security rules to start securing my firestore database.

I am including a caricature of my flask `main.py` file for reference.

```py
# main.py

from google.cloud import firestore

from mylibrary import function_that_fetches_user_data
from mylibrary2 import function_that_writes_user_content

def validate_cookie(protected_function):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        # handle cookie validation
        # run protected function
    return wrapper

# The dashboard is meant to display user data and user content to the user.  
# It is not meant to be seen by other users.
@app.route("/user_dashboard")
@validate_cookie
def dashboard():
    user_id = get_uid_from_cookie
    firestore_client = firestore.Client()
    user_data = function_that_fetches_user_data(user_id, firestore_client)
    return render_template('dashboard.html', user_data)

# The write function creates user content that should only be accessible to the author 
# and the system/app.  
@app.route("/write_user_content")
@validate_cookie
def write_user_content():
    user_id = get_uid_from_cookie
    firestore_client = firestore.Client()
    result = function_that_writes_user_content(user_id, firestore_client)
    return render_template('success.html', result)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Security rules are only necessary to control access coming from web and mobile clients.  Backend SDK accessing Firestore actually bypass security rules altogether, so writing any rules at all won't change the behavior of your backend code at all.

If you simply do not directly access the database from web or mobile, then you can set the security rules to reject all access, and that's fine.

```
match /{document=**} {
  allow read, write: if false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll use this then. But just to clarify,  if there are no security rules defined, I'm assuming that the firestore database is wide open and is vulnerable?

Comment: It's not possible to have no rules.  You need at least one rule to be valid.